# How can I switch my sound output between mono and stereo in an app using the ALSA API?

Tags: c++, alsa

There are possibilities to do this in the `asoundrc` config file, but I need an application-level solution without the need to restart the app. So far, I've had this line of code in the init part of my app:

```cpp
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels (cd::output_handle, cd::output_params, (unsigned int) 2);
```

The audio data stream comes from the CD drive, so that it always features 2 channels (stereo). Can I simply set the channel count to 1 on the fly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the hw parameters only when the PCM stream is not running. See: https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm.html. You need to fill first the `snd_pcm_hw_params_t` structure with the desired configuration, and then apply this configuration with `snd_pcm_hw_params()`. For instance:

```
int err;
snd_pcm_t *handle;
snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

err = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default" //, ...
//...
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);
//...

if((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2)) == 0) {
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you. So I will have to pause the audio stream, then apply the code you proposed me, and finally resume playing the stream, right?

Comment: No, I don't think that `snd_pcm_pause()` is enough (and not every device supports that). The stream can be stopped using the `snd_pcm_drop()` or `snd_pcm_drain()`. You don't need to `snd_pcm_close()`, though.

Comment: No use: `snd_pcm_drain ()` provokes error #77 (invalid handle). `snd_pcm_drop ()` dies work, but invoking `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels ()` ALWAYS ends up in a `stack smashing detected`, followed by an immediate abort.

Comment: Post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), in this or another question.

Comment: OK, I haven't had the chance to break the issue down with a minimal example, but I could at least apply a successful workaround: Mono / stereo is now changed after the current track has been played. At least for me, it's sufficient.